# Изменить стиль оглавления в приложениях

Tags: latex, tex

Оформляю дипломную работу. В конце работы должны быть приложения, которые должны отображаться в содержании определённым образом, в отличии от самой работы, примерный вид:

```
Содержание

1 Название главы ......страница
  1.1 Название секции ......страница
     1.1.1 Название пункта ......страница
Приложение А ......страница
Приложение Б ......страница
```

То есть:

1. Если в приложении есть секции - они *не должны* отображаться
2. Заголовки приложений тоже не должны отображаться

Постарался выделить минимальный рабочий код, на котором видна проблема:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
%===================================================
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа
\usepackage{tocloft} %пакет для оформления оглавления
\usepackage{titlesec} %пакет для оформления заголовков
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %добавление списка источников в оглавление
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} %добавление приложений в оглавление

% Установка параметров для документа
%===================================================
\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setotherlanguage{english} % объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}, Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\parindent=1.25cm %красная строка

\renewcaptionname{russian}{\contentsname}{\normalsize \MakeUppercase{Содержание}} %заголовок оглавления
\renewcaptionname{russian}{\appendixname}{Приложение} %заголовок приложений
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % заполнение точками Глав в оглавлении

%параметры заголовков разделов (глав)
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter~}{0pt}{\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{\parindent}{0bp}{2\baselineskip}
%параметры заголовков подразделов (секций)
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        Титульный лист
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \tableofcontents{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \clearpage
    
    \chapter{Первая}
        \section{Первый}
            \subsection{первый}
            
    \chapter{Вторая}
        \section{Второй}
            \subsection{второй}
            
    \begin{appendices}  
        \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\centering\appendixname~\thechapter}{0pt}{\centering\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
        \titlespacing{\chapter}{\parindent}{0bp}{\baselineskip}
        \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
        \titlespacing{\section}{0bp}{0bp}{\baselineskip}
        
        \chapter{Первое приложение}
            \section{Первый}
            
            \section{Второй}
            
            \section{Третий}
            
        \chapter{Второе приложение}
            \section{Первый}
            
            \section{Второй}
            
            \section{Третий}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Находил около 2,5 решения этого вопроса, но ни одно не работает:

1. Команда `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` - компилятор ругается (и похожее решение - объявить отдельную команду под это)
2. Пакет `tocvsec2` с командой `\settocdepth{chapter}` - просто не работает, полный игнор

Есть подозрения, что имеются какие-то конфликты - поэтому ни один из способов нерабочий. Что касается удаления заголовков из содержания - тоже не нашёл никакого решения, но подозреваю, что его нужно подставить в окружение `appendices`. Искал в том числе и в документации пакета `tocloft`, который использую.

Дистрибутив: TeXLive

Компилятор: XeLaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я внес незначительные изменения в Ваш код и, если я правильно понял чего Вы добивались, все получилось.

1. Чтобы удалить названия приложений верхнего уровня я просто воспользовался штатным средством - для секций в LaTeX можно указывать как необязательный параметр альтернативное имя, которое будет отображаться в колонтитулах и оглавлении. Если сделать просто пустое имя, типа `\chapter[]{Название раздела}`, то тогда этот раздел в оглавление совсем не попадет, но если обмануть компилятор и скормить туда что-то фиктивное (я в одном случае использую вертикальный фантом, а в другом просто пустую внутристрочную формулу), то всё срабатывает как надо. Ну, можно конечно придраться к немного большему пробелу от метки приложения до отточия, но может и так сойдет?
2. Чтобы убрать из оглавления заголовки меньшего уровня у меня получилось использовать пакет `tocvsec2` с командой `\settocdepth{chapter}`. И естественно, при любых изменениях заголовков (и всего, что касается сборки оглавления) компилировать документ нужно как минимум два раза. После секции с приложениями я еще добавил необязательную (здесь) команду `\resettocdepth`, которая должна вернуть учет уровня заголовков для оглавлений (вдруг после приложений еще какой-то блок будет? :-) ).

Если что, я тестировал всё это в XeLaTeX от TeXLive 2020 под MS Win10. И я слегка изменил строку с указанием языка по умолчанию, поскольку мой компилятор не принимает опцию `[forceheadingpunctuation=false]`.

Собственно, ниже сам код и результат компиляции.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}


% Подключение пакетов
%===================================================
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}   %внутренняя кодировка

\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа
\usepackage{tocloft} %пакет для оформления оглавления
\usepackage{titlesec} %пакет для оформления заголовков
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %добавление списка источников в оглавление
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} %добавление приложений в оглавление

\usepackage{tocvsec2}

% Установка параметров для документа
%===================================================
%\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setdefaultlanguage[indentfirst=true]{russian}  
\setotherlanguage{english} % объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}, Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\parindent=1.25cm %красная строка

\renewcaptionname{russian}{\contentsname}{\normalsize \MakeUppercase{Содержание}} %заголовок оглавления
\renewcaptionname{russian}{\appendixname}{Приложение} %заголовок приложений
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % заполнение точками Глав в оглавлении

%параметры заголовков разделов (глав)
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter~}{0pt}{\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{\parindent}{0bp}{2\baselineskip}
%параметры заголовков подразделов (секций)
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        Титульный лист
    \end{titlepage}

    
    \tableofcontents{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \clearpage
    
    \chapter{Первая}
        \section{Первый}
            \subsection{первый}
            
    \chapter{Вторая}
        \section{Второй}
            \subsection{второй}
     
    \begin{appendices}  
        \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\centering\appendixname~\thechapter}{0pt}{\centering\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
        \titlespacing{\chapter}{\parindent}{0bp}{\baselineskip}
        \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
        \titlespacing{\section}{0bp}{0bp}{\baselineskip}
        
        \settocdepth{chapter}   
        \chapter[\vphantom{A}]{Первое приложение}
            \section{Первый}
            
            \section{Второй}
            
            \section{Третий}
            
        \chapter[\(\)]{Второе приложение}
            \section{Первый}
            
            \section{Второй}
            
            \section{Третий}
    \end{appendices}
    \resettocdepth
\end{document}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, но Ваше решение сработало только частично - по 1му пункту. Тут всё, как нужно (разве что я использовал \hspace{0pt}). А вот по 2му такой же результат - полное игнорирование команды и\или пакета. TeXStudio, вроде как умный - компилирует по 2 раза, но на всякий случай прогнал вручную несколько раз - бесполезно. Конечно, у меня конфиг немного отличается: TeXLive 2021 под Manjaro. Но не уверен, что это как-то влияет.

Comment: @Kontzid, ну, тогда скорее это баг в обновленной версии пакета. Могу предложить пару костылей вместо него: 1) использовать звездочную версию команд \section*{}`, правда, тогда и нумерации не будет; 2) можно вообще отказаться для приложений от стандартной рубрикации, а формировать заголовки руками - и здесь можно вручную добавить пункты в оглавление в том виде, в котором хочется.

Comment: 2ой вариант я фактически и осуществил пока, как временное решение :) Пробовал задать этот вопрос на tex.stackexchange, но там меня в серьёзные дебри чистого TeX'а окунули... И решение оказалось рабочим, но для этого конкретного примера :D Когда попытался внедрить его в свою работу - всё вообще сломалось и перестало компилиться.

Comment: Отмечу Ваше решение, как рабочее - проблема решилась сама собой, хотя весьма необычным образом: дело в том, что работа составная и приложение находится в отдельном файле, который подключается командой \include - виновата именно эта команда. При замене на \input пакет заработал, как нужно и всё стало отображаться.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вот это:

http://mydebianblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/latex.html

Мне кажется. там как раз про это:

> если в документе есть Appendix, то отображать в оглавлении его
> subsections совсем не обязательно.
>
> Для этого есть пакет tocvsec2 который позволяет нам менять уровень
> отображения разделов там, где нам надо.

Comment: Я написал в вопросе, что пробовал это решение и оно не работает.

Comment: @Kontzid - "пробовал это решение" - Возможно, я чего-то не уловил, но у Вас в преамбуле нет оператора *\usepackage{tocvsec2}*

Comment: запись под кодом: "Находил около 2,5 решения этого вопроса, но ни одно не работает:
1. Команда \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} - компилятор ругается (и похожее решение - объявить отдельную команду под это)
2. Пакет tocvsec2 с командой \settocdepth{chapter} - просто не работает, полный игнор". Код попытался сделать минимальный, поэтому убрал нерабочие варианты.